# Mongoose - renaming object key within array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have this one schema

```
{
  _id: "123456",
  id: "123",
  inventory: [
    {
      id: "foo",
      count: 0
    },
    {
      id: "bar",
      count: 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I wanted every "count" keys in the inventory array to be "price" which will look like this at the end:

```
{
  _id: "123456",
  id: "123",
  inventory: [
    {
      id: "foo",
      price: 0
    },
    {
      id: "bar",
      price: 3
    }
  ]
}
```

And I've tried this

```
Model.updateOne({ id: "123" }, { $unset: { inventory: [{ count: 1 }] } } )
```

But it seems to be deleting the "inventory" field itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing here is to try to use [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) but how the docs explain:

> `$rename` does not work if these fields are in array elements.

So is necessary to look for another method. So you can use this update with aggregation query:

This query uses mainly `$map`, `$arrayToObject` and `$objectToArray`. The trick here is:

- Create a new field called `inventory` (overwrite existing one)
- Iterate over every value of the array with `$map`, and then for each object in the array use `$objectToArray` to create an array and also iterate over that second array using again `$map`.
- Into this second iteration create fields `k` and `v`. Field `v` will be the same (you don't want to change the value, only the key). And for field `k` you have to change only the one whose match with your condition, i.e. only change from `count` to `price`. If this condition is not matched then the key remain.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      inventory: {
        $map: {
          input: "$inventory",
          in: {
            $arrayToObject: {
              $map: {
                input: {$objectToArray: "$$this"},
                in: {
                  k: {
                    $cond: [
                      {
                        $eq: ["$$this.k","count"]
                      },
                      "price",
                      "$$this.k"
                    ]
                  },
                  v: "$$this.v"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jdpkAhLDlrX)

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i've searched for